# Web scrape html gas stations

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Given this link http://www.nj.gov/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml I want to scrape each gas station and its info

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=requests.get("http://www.nj.gov/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
for x in soup.find_all('p'):
    print x
```

what is the next step in extracting the correct data?

Comment: Use a browser extension that will point out the html elements you need. It'll give you the exact tags to find. I recommend using this one: http://selectorgadget.com/

Comment: I need this to be done in python...

Comment: @ziggy That's not what we was saying. He was saying that to identify what tags you need to extract in the python code, use a tool to help you see what those tags are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Here's the final code piggybacking off of @Dan-Dev. It's kind of hacky... Excuse the length, I didn't have time to write shorter code.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

def is_phone_number(txt):
    r = re.compile(r"(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})")
    return r.match(txt)

def is_gas_type(txt):
    return any(term in txt.lower() for term in ['lead', 'diesel'])

def is_lat_lon(txt):
    return any(term in txt.lower() for term in ['lat', 'lon'])

def is_hour_of_operation(txt):
    return any(term in txt.lower() for term in ['24 hrs', ' am ', ' pm ', 'm-f'])

def str_colon_list_to_str_float_dict(rlist):
    """["a:1.0", "b:2.0"] => {"a":1.0, "b":2.0}"""
    intermediate_dict = dict(map(lambda s: s.split(':'), rlist))
    return dict((k, float(v)) for k, v in intermediate_dict.iteritems())

page = requests.get("http://www.nj.gov/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[5]

gas_stations = []
for x in table.find_all('td', {'valign': 'top', 'colspan': None, 'width': None}):
    gas_station = []
    # split text on line breaks and then remove whitespace
    for y in x.text.splitlines():
        line = ' '.join(y.split())
        gas_station.append(line)
    # skip lines consisting of only empty strings
    if not ('' in set(gas_station) and len(set(gas_station)) == 1):
        gas_stations.append(gas_station)

gas_stations_dict = {}
for gas_station in gas_stations:
    gas_station_dict = {}
    address_list = []
    lat_long_list = []
    for i, g in enumerate(gas_station):
        g = g.encode("utf-8")
        if i == 0:
            gas_station_dict['Name'] = g
        elif is_phone_number(g):
            gas_station_dict['Phone Number'] = g
        elif is_lat_lon(g):
            lat_long_list.append(g)
        elif is_gas_type(g):
            gas_station_dict['Gas Type'] = g
        elif is_hour_of_operation(g):
            gas_station_dict['Hours of Operation'] = g
        else:
            address_list.append(g)
    gas_station_dict['Coordinates'] = str_colon_list_to_str_float_dict(lat_long_list)
    gas_station_dict['Address'] = ' '.join(address_list)

    gas_stations_dict[gas_station_dict['Name']] = gas_station_dict

pprint(gas_stations_dict)
```

**Result:**

```
    {'Bayside Facility': {'Address': '4294 Rt. 47 Leesburg',
                           'Coordinates': {'Latitude': 39.23339997,
                                           'Longitude': -74.96568202},
                           'Gas Type': 'Unleaded / Diesel',
                           'Hours of Operation': 'Open 24 Hrs',
                           'Name': 'Bayside Facility',
                           'Phone Number': '856-785-0040 X-5429'},
     'Bedminster DOT': {'Address': '455 Rt. 202/206 South Pluckemin',
                         'Coordinates': {'Latitude': 40.65123677,
                                         'Longitude': -74.64499021},
                         'Gas Type': 'Unleaded / Diesel',
                         'Hours of Operation': 'Open 24 Hrs',
                         'Name': 'Bedminster DOT',
                         'Phone Number': '908-234-2130'},
        ...
        }
```

**My Old Answer:**

I tried using Selector Gadget, like I mentioned in my comment, but I didn't find any consistent pattern in the html that would grab all the station names. I scrape a lot, and I have the same trouble with a lot of government sites. I don't know if this is incompetence or if it's done on purpose to prevent scraping... Anyway, here's some code that prints out some info:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
page=requests.get("http://www.nj.gov/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
for x in soup.find_all('p'):
    for y in x:
        if isinstance(y, NavigableString):
            print y.encode("utf-8")
        else:
            for z in y:
                if isinstance(z, NavigableString):
                    print z.encode("utf-8")
```

From this point, you can modify it depending on the info you want. Just eyeballing it, it looks like the last line for every station group is "Longitude".

Finally, when done, I'd eyeball it to make sure you have all the info you need. For example, Folsom DOT does not get pulled when you feed find_all the p tag.

Comment: this returned nothing for me when ran

Comment: yeah idk nothing again...is it returning info for you?

Comment: Strange ... was there an error at least. What OS, IDE, etc?

Comment: windows 10, pyscripter, no error, python 2.7

Comment: I put that code in a file and ran it on the command line. I have a Mac and Python 2.7. Can you try running it from the command line? My memory's a bit hazy when it comes to Windows, but you would have to add your Python interpreter to the PATH if you don't already. (https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path). Next, save the code in a file and type `python filename.py` in the command line.

Comment: strange... some stuff printed out...

Comment: then got this error `Open 24 Hrs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abid.py", line 8, in <module>
    print y
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 27: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: im trying to think of other options, maybe convert it to JSON? do you think that might be easier to work with?

Comment: try adding first line of script above imports: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: I edited ...  appended .encode("utf-8") to the print statements. daveedwards' suggestion would work, but haven't tried it myself.

Comment: wow, okay last thing how would I separately  get each object? like I want Buena DOT all that info... then next one... on and on

Comment: Your question only asked for the next step. ;) Haha ... this is more like a rough draft to give some ideas. I'll work on it a bit later today, but I have to get back to the office. Sorry to leave you hanging.

Comment: all good you have been a major help, I find web scraping very difficult

Comment: wow you're a beast, thanks! any good python web tutorials you reccomend?

Answer (score 1):

You have very little to select from given the HTML. So you can de-select what you dn't want. You want the 6th table, you don't want td elements with the "colspan" attributes or any "width" attributes. But the td elements must have valign top.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=requests.get("http://www.nj.gov/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[5]
for x in table.find_all('td', {'valign': 'top', 'colspan': None, 'width':None}):
    print (x.text)
    print ('#############')
```

**UPDATED** in response to comment

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint
import re

page=requests.get("http://www.nj.gov/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[5]

tmps = [i.text for i in table.find_all('td', {'valign': 'top', 'colspan': None, 'width':None})]
my_dict = dict()
for tmp in tmps:
    if len(tmp.strip()) != 0:
        # Clean up the output and add to dictionary.
        my_dict[re.sub( '\s+', ' ', tmp.split('\n', 1)[0] ).strip()] = re.sub( '\s+', ' ', tmp ).strip()

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint (my_dict)
```

Outputs:

```
{   'Bayside Facility': 'Bayside Facility 4294 Rt. 47 Leesburg Open 24 Hrs '
                        'Unleaded / Diesel 856-785-0040 X-5429 Latitude: '
                        '39.23339997 Longitude: -74.96568202',
    'Bedminster DOT': 'Bedminster DOT 455 Rt. 202/206 South Pluckemin Open 24 '
                      'Hrs Unleaded / Diesel 908-234-2130 Latitude: '
                      '40.65123677 Longitude: -74.64499021',
    'Berlin DOT': 'Berlin DOT 36 Walker Ave. Berlin Open 24 Hrs Unleaded / '
                  'Diesel 856-767-7717 Latitude: 39.80369329 Longitude: '
                  '-74.93442722',
    'Bloomsbury DOT': 'Bloomsbury DOT 1000 Rt. 173 Bloomsbury Open 24 Hrs '
                      'Unleaded / Diesel 908-479-4851 Latitude: 40.66078600 '
                      'Longitude: -75.06664165',
    'Bordentown DOT': 'Bordentown DOT Dunns Mill Rd. -off Rt. 130 Bordentown '
                      'Unleaded -Open 24 Hrs Diesel – 7:30 am -3:45 pm M-F '
                      '609-298-2980 Latitude: 40.13178135 Longitude: '
                      '-74.71658907',
...
```

But it misses two gas stations:

```
<td valign="top" width="235"><p>Elizabeth DOT<br />
<td align="top" width="264">Summit DOT<br />
```

as they have width attributes, given the HTML there is no way to select these too.

Comment: wow this is great okay last thing, if I want to store each gas station in a dictionary with the name of gas station of being the key and the rest the values how would I incorporate that?